# What is the probability of getting 3 questions wrong on a TRUE/FALSE test of 5 questions?

Tags: probability

I figure the answer is (where binomial notation is choose)

$$\binom{5}{3}\cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3$$

But is this correct? It isn't homework, just genuine curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers are correct, but explain nothing. I see you're familiar with binomials and probability, so I'll skip all the boring definitions.

First of all, we can imagine our result at the test with something like this (formally, this is a vector in $ \left( \mathbb{Z}_4 \right)^5 $ ).

$ \left( 0, 1, 2, 3, 1 \right) $

where $0$ stands for "I got the right answer and it was false", $1$ stands for "I got the right answer and it was true", $2$ stands for "I got the wrong answer and it was false" and $3$ stands for "I got the wrong answer and it was true".

The favorable cases are a vector with three $0$ or $1$ out of five total answers. The probability of this event would be $\dfrac{2^5}{4^5}$ since for each right answer we may choose $0$ or $1$, and for each wrong answer we may choose $2$ or $3$; by the way, we don't need any order here, so we must multiply it for the number of permutations of those 3 right answers in the 5-vector: $\dbinom{5}{3}$.

So here you are:

$P = \dbinom{5}{3} \cdot \dfrac{2^5}{4^5} = \dbinom{5}{3} \cdot \dfrac{1}{2^5}$

Answer (score 1):

No, it is actually ${{{5}\choose{3}}.{({\frac{1}{2}})^3}{({\frac{1}{2}})^2}}$

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing between probability and number of ways. The answer is simply n times

### $\frac{1}{2^3}\frac{1}{2^2}$

n times is the time where you apply the $OR$ condition that which 3 are wrong and other two have to be right.

The answer :

### $\binom{5}{3}\frac{1}{2^3}\frac{1}{2^2}$

Comment: Why do we multiply it by $\frac{1}{2^2}$? I understand $\frac{1}{2^3}$ because that is the amount that we want to get wrong.  Shouldn't we add 5 choose 2 if we were to multiply by 2^(-2)?

Comment: @Jason But the other 2 have to be wrong. Otherwise it may include cases of 4 wrong and 1 right.

Comment: @Jason When you choose 3 the other 2 are automatically chosen as the left ones. That is why 5 choose 2 = 5 choose 3

Answer (score 1):

The binomial distribution states that the probability of $k$ successes among $n$ trials with the probability of a success in a trial is $p$ is:

$P(x = k)$ = $\binom{n}{k}\cdot p^{k}\cdot (1-p)^{n-k}$. Use $n = 5$, $k = 3$, $p = \dfrac{1}{2}$ to get the answer.